# Как получить прогресс загрузки файла на сервер используя Uri?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, okhttp, uri

Всех приветствую. Подскажите пожалуйста,как получить прогресс загрузки файла на сервер используя okhttp,если у нас есть только Uri. Видел примеры для файла. Также видел примеры,как okhttp работает с uri. Вопрос как объеденить эти примеры (что-то не очень могу сообразить). Если у кого-то есть решение,как получить прогресс загрузки файла,используя uri,поделитесь им пожалуйста. Заранее благодарю всех за помощь.

Comment: Вы на сервер файл/данные POST запросом отсылаете?

Comment: @Style-7 Да,на сервер через okhttp.

Comment: [тык](https://getstream.io/blog/android-upload-progress/)

Comment: @Style-7 Ой,а там вроде не используется uri.

Comment: А вы используйте) Разница лишь в том как получить `InputStream` и метаданные, но это уже не про okhttp.

Comment: @woesss Так вот я и спрашиваю,как объединить пример с uri и пример с прогрессом в один класс.